# INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE UPDATE

Tags: php, mysql

what I am trying todo is make a highscores page and each time it updates I want it to go into the same entry, so if Username is a duplicate I want it to update with the current information and then the information posted, after looking at some stuff on the internet I tried the code below and that gives me the error Column count doesn't match value count at row 1. Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong as I am very new to PHP + MySql.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO $table(Username, Time, Videos, Credits) VALUES ('$user', '$time', '$videos', '$credits',
    'ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE', Time='Time+$time', Videos='Videos+$videos', Credits='Credits+$credits')", $conn);
```

Comment: warning, your code is susceptible to sql injection

Comment: I have got some protection against that in the script, I have tried it myself and it is patched.

Comment: @Daniel Not necessarily, we don't know what he's doing to his variables before he puts them into the query, he could be calling `mysql_real_escape_string`. @Daniel you're probably better off creating another table for users, and you can do a simple lookup so see if that Username exists, if not create it, and put the Id of the user in the highscore table.

Comment: @JLevet - when ever i see straight string replacement or concatenation, i throw up my warning.

Comment: Thanks anyway, I am calling `mysql_real_escape_string` for all of the variables used.

Comment: Daniel, `mysql_real_escape_string` or any other scheme for that matter does **NOT** protect you when using dynamic table names!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The syntax is incorrect, you are passing the 'on duplicate update' and it's rules as values to the insert. The correct query would be

```
mysql_query("
    INSERT INTO
        $table(Username, Time, Videos, Credits)
    VALUES
        ('$user', '$time', '$videos', '$credits')
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
        Time=Time+'$time',
        Videos=Videos+'$videos',
        Credits=Credits+'$credits'
    ",
    $conn
);
```

Comment: Fixed the SQL-injection (other than the dynamic table name) for ya.

Answer (score 1):

This code is a SQL-injection nightmare.

Make sure to check dynamic table names against a white-list like so:

```
$user = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['user']);
$time = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['time']);
$videos = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['videos']);
$credits = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['credits']);

$allowed_tables = array('table1', 'table2');  
$table = $_POST['table'];
$query = "";  //do nothing

if (in_array($table, $allowed_tables)) {   //<<-- check against whitelist.
  $query = "
    INSERT INTO
        $table(Username, Time, Videos, Credits)
    VALUES
        ('$user', '$time', '$videos', '$credits')
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
        Time=Time+'$time',
        Videos=Videos+'$videos',
        Credits=Credits+'$credits'
    "
}    
mysql_query($query, $con);
```